# How I can override specific styles of MUI Accordian in next.js by using css module

Tags: css, sass, next.js, material-ui, css-selectors

I want to override the default MUI CSS of the accordion component and I want to do this using the CSS module but problem is that the class is dynamically added by mui. Hence I cannot target that class directly.

I tried this below solution but it is not working:-

**Css code:-**

```
`.accordian_summary {
  &:global(.MuiAccordionSummary-root) {
    padding: 0px !important;
  }
  &:global(.MuiAccordionSummary-content) {
    display: block !important;
  }
}`
```

**JSX Code:-**
[Accordian component code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywVxs.png)

**DOM Tree structure and the class which I want to override**
[Browser code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9DbM.png)

*Note:- One of the CSS is getting applied i.e

```
`&:global(.MuiAccordionSummary-root) {     padding: 0px !important;   } `
```

but this is not working

```
` &:global(.MuiAccordionSummary-content) {
    display: block !important;
  }`
```

Please help if possible and Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The element which contains the `.MuiAccordionSummary-content` class does not have `.accordian_summary` (it's a descendant of it), which means that CSS rule won't apply to it.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```css
div[class*="MuiAccordionSummary-root"] {
  display: block;
}
```

For example to change style for input error label:

```css
label[class*="Mui-error"] {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```